# Java error on code

Tags: java, syntax-error

I keep getting this errors, and I don't really know what it means
    symptom:
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
    at Board.isAvailable(Board.java:63)
    at Board.putSpotOnBoard(Board.java:80)

```
 public int putSpotOnBoard(int place, char mark)
    {
      if(isAvailable(place) == true)---------> line 80
        {
            boardNumbers[place] = mark;
            return place;
        }s
        else
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the main() method you used to run this program?

Answer (score 2):

The value `9` was passed to the `isAvailable` method, but the array length is 9, so the valid indices are 0 through 8.

Check if the passed in value is within range.  If it's not within the range, then return `false`, assuming you want out-of-range indices not to be "available".

Or you can stop whatever method is calling `isAvailable` from passing in an invalid index in the first place.